# initramfs - boot failure after umount -a or ntfslabel?

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I connected a USB drive to my xbmc/ubuntu system and as it was named "New Volume" I tried to change the label using ntfslabel. As I'm a newbie when it comes to linux and hardware I stumbled around a bit, ran 'umount -a' and also tried to format the new disk with "mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sdc3"

At some point I was getting strange results so did a reboot and now I'm staring at:

Gave up waiting for root device. etc etc.
(initramfs)

Obviously I hosed something, but I thought since I was only messing with an empty USB drive I would be ok. I removed the USB drive, rebooted, and I'm still seeing this message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My actions were a red herring - it turns out one of my disks, defined in fstab, died. This dead disk prevented me from booting. I realized this by unplugging all but the boot disk and when I booted successfully added them back in one by one until I found the poison disk. I removed the disk and the system works as expected.

Lesson learned - when it doesn't make sense that your actions didn't cause a problem, there's a (slight) chance that it was just coincidence.